# Request a Windows Phone 7.5 Location

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to track 5 windows phone 7.5 for a experiment and I have try using an app (that I am developing for that experiment) but the app must be active and that's not possible for all readings, I was looking online and I find something similar that Microsoft has done with the find my phone service,

https://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/find

Anyone knows how can i call that service outside the website or any other way to accomplish this task
i need GEO position every 15 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going to be able to locate the phone unless the application is either running in the foreground or the background on the phone. You can't compare what microsoft is able to do with what you are able to do. They have implemented many things in Windows Phone 7.5 and 8 that a normal developer cannot do. Microsoft is not alone in doing this, nearly all mobile operating systems, have features that are not possible to duplicate as a developer.

Doing a quick search on the matter, I see nothing that should prevent you from running an application in the background, so you can report the location of the phone to a web service of some kind.